# Use Full Text Search for Persian Language

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, farsi

I see **[supported language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176076(v=sql.110).aspx)** in full text search (SQL Server 2012).
Persian (Farsi) does not exist in list. But as I know, there is a way to use full text search for Persian language with adding custom dictionary, using Arabic language and etc.

Please help and give me some references and guidance for using Persian language in Full Text Search of SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes FTS doesn't support Persian language, but that doesn't mean it won't work with it. Only `inflectional` queries such as `WHERE CONTAINS(docexcerpt, N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, presentation)');` are not supported for Persian language. Because these types of queries need a lot of information about the structure and grammar of the specified language. Otherwise you can use queries like `SELECT id, title, docexcerpt FROM dbo.Documents WHERE CONTAINS(docexcerpt, N'سلام');`

[More info in Persian](https://www.dntips.ir/courses/details/13)

Comment: the link you provided isn't valid anymore.

Comment: The broken link has been fixed.