# Full-text Index stop list for Persian language

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I need to customize Full-text search for Persian language. And customize Stop/Noise words and synonyms for this language.

My SQL Server version is 2016 and full-text search is installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Full Text Search in sql server 2012 for Persian Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989545/how-to-use-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2012-for-persian-language)

Comment: I checked with the code below and found that Persian is not in the builtin languages. SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_languages

Comment: I'm taking advantage of it now and it works perfectly for me.I'm looking for a way to change Stop words and customize for Persian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For use Persian language in SQL Server Stop list, Full text catalog and etc just we should use `Neutral`. If you don't use `Neutral` in catalog I suggested for you change it to `Neutral`, sometimes this is empty like below:

[image]

Your problem solve by this query for any language:

```
--View Stoplist word
SELECT w.stoplist_id,
   l.name,
   w.stopword,
   w.language
FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords AS w
   INNER JOIN sys.fulltext_stoplists AS l
     ON w.stoplist_id = l.stoplist_id;

-- Stopwords list
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST StopListCustome;
GO

-- Add a stopword
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST StopListCustome
    ADD 'SQL' LANGUAGE 'English';
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST StopListCustome 
    ADD 'از' LANGUAGE 'Neutral';
```

Find this document and code on [github](https://github.com/AmirNBA9/SQLAssistant/tree/master/FullTextSearch)

And also you can use  below lists for add any stop list text in Persian and English :

> [Download English stoplist](http://bigdata-ir.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/stopwordsEN.docx)
>
> [Download Persian or Farsi stoplist](http://bigdata-ir.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/stopwords-Farsi1.docx) for many words
>
> [Download Persian or Farsi stoplist](http://bigdata-ir.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/stopwords-Farsi2.docx) for standard
> words

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution.

By default when you create a full text index it is associated with a system stoplist. The default stoplist has more than 150 words for the English language.

[configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

[full-text-search-stoplist-and-stopword](https://codingcanvas.com/full-text-search-stoplist-and-stopword/)

**Just open this file and then add your words**

[SQL Server Path]\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\FTData\tsglobal.xml

```
<XML ID="Microsoft Search Thesaurus">
<thesaurus xmlns="x-schema:tsSchema.xml">
<diacritics_sensitive>0</diacritics_sensitive>
    <expansion>
        <sub>Internet Explorer</sub>
        <sub>IE</sub>
        <sub>IE5</sub>
    </expansion>
    <expansion>
        <sub>سازگار سیستم خاورمیانه</sub>
        <sub>ستیران</sub>
    </expansion>
        <expansion>
        <sub>آبجی</sub>
        <sub>خواهر</sub>
    </expansion>
    <replacement>
        <pat>NT5</pat>
        <pat>W2K</pat>
        <sub>Windows 2000</sub>
    </replacement>
    <expansion>
        <sub>run</sub>
        <sub>jog</sub>
    </expansion>
</thesaurus>
```

And then execute this SQL command.

```
EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file 0;
```

And for creating a custom stop list just flow these code:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST [PersianStopList]
```

And then add your stop list

```
    ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [PersianStopList] ADD 'از' LANGUAGE 'Neutral';
```

Complete information in the Persian language:
https://www.dotnettips.info/courses/topics/13#/page/1/date/desc

Comment: I check it, its good. i have a suggest for this experience in answer below. wish you the best.